# How to add Bearer token to requestify post method in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requestify

How can i pass Bearer token with post method. I tried with postman but getting this response "Error: Unauthorized Access. Request is not authorized"

```
            await turnContext.sendActivity(`${await requestify.request(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                auth:{
                    "Bearer":access_token // token
                }
            }).then(async function (res) {
                console.log(res.body);
                return res.body;
            })}`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/ranm8/requestify#auth--username-string-password-string--) the `auth` property is used for basic auth only, so just add the Authorization header manually

```
await requestify.request(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers :{
        Authorization:"Bearer " + access_token // token
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Bearer` as prefix to your token:

```
 await turnContext.sendActivity(`${await requestify.request(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                auth:{
                    `Bearer ${access_token}` // token
                }
            }).then(async function (res) {
                console.log(res.body);
                return res.body;
            })}`);
```